# Trying to get user input with document.getElementById, but it's not updating from my default value

Tags: javascript, html

HTML fragment (in `<body>`):

```
<label for="name">Delimiter (max 1 character):</label>

<input type="text" id="delimiter" name="delimiter" required
minlength="0" maxlength="1" size="1">

<input type="file" name="filename" id="fileInput">

<div class="csv"></div>

<script src="csv.js"></script>
```

JS fragment:

```
async function fileToLines(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      parsedLines = e.target.result.split(/\r|\n|\r\n/);
      resolve(parsedLines);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
  });
}

document
.getElementById('fileInput')
.addEventListener('change', async function(e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];

  if (file != undefined) {
    fileToLines(file).then( async id => {
      console.log(id)
      console.log(parsedLines)
      console.log(typeof id);

      var idInt = id.map(Number);
      var idFiltered = id.filter(function(v){return v!==''});

      console.log(idFiltered)

      for(let id of idFiltered) {
        const row = await getRelease(id);
        allRows.push(row);
      }
      download();
    });
  }
});

function getRelease(idFiltered) {
  return fetch(`https://api.*****.com/releases/${idFiltered}`, {
    'User-Agent': 'Dispodger/0.1',
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    if (data.message === 'Release not found.') {
      return { error: `Release with ID ${idFiltered} does not exist` };
    } else {
      const id = data.id;
      const artists = data.artists ? data.artists.map(artist => artist.name) : [];
      const country = data.country || 'Unknown';
      // const delimiter = "|";
      const delimiter = document.getElementById("delimiter").defaultValue = "|"; 

[...]
```

I'm wondering if it is somehow doing `getRelease()` before it actually gets any user-entered delimiter, so it never has a chance to use any non-default input.

Looking at [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-set-default-value/6914/5), and I wonder if I need to either a) write a `SetDefaultValue()` function or b) set a default value in the HTML? I see someone there mentions "moving the script tag to immediately before the ", so I guess the order of the HTML does affect the order of execution. Perhaps my JS is running before the user's non-default `delimiter` is ever 'detected', if that's the right word.

Also wondering if I need some [onload event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)? Not sure how I would code that or even where it would go though.

I tried this in `getRelease`:

```
  const delimiter = document.getElementById("delimiter").defaultValue = "|";
  delimiter = document.getElementById("delimiter").value;
```

But it comes back 'invalid assignment' for the 2nd line, so that can't be right.

Is `document.getElementById` somehow checking index.html for the `delimiter` value, where it should actually be looking at csv.html?

Any suggestions please? TIA.

Comment: `const delimiter = document.getElementById("delimiter").defaultValue = "|";` um, you are setting it to equal "|" and you cannot reassign a const. Is there a reason you do not set "|" in the HTML itself? Why not something like `const delimiter = document.getElementById("delimiter").value || "|";`

Comment: *"But it comes back 'invalid assignment' for the 2nd line"* - Because it's a `const`.  If you want to re-assign the variable, use `let` instead.

Comment: Great, many thanks, both of you! I've got it now.